# Need a select tag to run javascript across documents

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a chrome extension and I am almost done. However I just need my popup dropdown to work to complete the extension. In one file (popup.html) I have a select tag that has..

```
<select id="currency">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>
```

I need each option to run a script from the script file (script.js) the scripts needed are..

```
   function prices() {
    var priceList = document.getElementsByClassName('item-amount');
    var i;
    fx.settings = { from: "USD", to: "GBP" };
    for (i = 0; i < priceList.length; i += 1) {
        var price = priceList[i].textContent;
        var newPrice = price.replace(/,/g , "");
        newPrice = newPrice / 100;
        newPrice = (fx.convert(newPrice)).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementsByClassName('item-amount')[i].innerHTML = "<span class='icon-logo'></span>" + price + "<span class='new-price'> (" + newPrice + " GBP)</span>";
        document.getElementsByClassName('new-price')[i].style.fontSize = "smaller";
    };
};
```

*The script will be altered based on each option in the list I just need to know how to apply this script to one and then just copy it to the others.*

I have looked everywhere and no where provides an answer that applies to this formatting.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` for call of a function every time the `option` selected.

```
<select id="currency" onchange="prices()">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>
```